# Find next text by search and highlight not works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, search

When search any text on search box, it can be find and highlighted the correct text, but when search next/new text, it's unable to find the next/new text, it's not working when search again, i'm unable to find the issue. The **JS** below.

**JS**

```
$('button#search').click(function() {
 var page = $('#ray-all_text');
   var pageText = page.html().replace("<span>", "").replace("</span>");
    var searchedText = $('#searchfor').val();
    var theRegEx = new RegExp("(" + searchedText + ")", "igm");
    var newHtml = pageText.replace(theRegEx, "<span>$1</span>");
    page.html(newHtml);
  $('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $("#ray-all_text span").offset().top }, 2000);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="ray-search">
  <div class="field" id="ray-search-form">
    <input type="text" id="searchfor" placeholder="what are you searching for?" />
    <button type="button" id="search">Press to Find!</button>
  </div>
</div>

<article id="ray-all_text">
  <p>
    This manual and web site, all information and data and photos contained herein, are the s...
  </p>
</article>
```

Please check the live Example: https://jsfiddle.net/gaezs6s8

Why is this happening? Is there a solution?

Comment: why it's all inside a settimeout function?

Comment: Yes, js load after 1 second, i need it to load after 1 second. any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to make a few validations before change all the `.html()` inside the text you want to avoid unexpected behaviors and improve the functionality.

First make a validation to avoid the 'space' as the first value on the input, this will let us later check if the input has a real value inside.

```
$('body').on('keydown', '#searchfor', function(e) {
    if (e.which === 32 &&  e.target.selectionStart === 0) {
      return false;
    }  
});
```

[Code from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23351225/2887133)

---

Now Please check the comments on your code:

```
//Create some vars to later check for: 
//['text you are searching', 'number of highlights','actual highlight']
var searching,
    limitsearch,
    countsearch;

$('button#search').click(function() {
    var searchedText = $('#searchfor').val();
    var page = $('#ray-all_text');

    //Now check if the text on input is valid
    if (searchedText != "") {
        //If the actual text on the input is different from the prev search
        if(searching != searchedText) {
            page.find('span').contents().unwrap();
            var pageText = page.html();
            var theRegEx = new RegExp("(" + searchedText + ")", "igm");
            var newHtml = pageText.replace(theRegEx, "<span>$1</span>");
            page.html(newHtml);
            //Set your variables to the actual search
            searching = searchedText;
            limitsearch = page.find('span').length;
            countsearch=0;
        } else {
            //If it's the same of the prev search then move to next item instead of repaint html
            countsearch<limitsearch-1 ? countsearch++ : countsearch=0;
            console.log(countsearch+'---'+limitsearch)
        }
        //Go to target search
        $('body').animate({
          scrollTop: $("#ray-all_text span").eq(countsearch).offset().top - 50}, 
        200);
     } else {
        alert('empty search')
     }
});
```

---

### [JqueryDemo](https://jsfiddle.net/gaezs6s8/3/)